# What is the undocumented block you get from THIRD on object/function in Rebol2?

Tags: function, object, rebol, rebol2

I've read internally R2 stores contexts as two tables, one for words and the other for values, so you can ask for them:

```
o: context [a: 1 b: 2]
>> first o
== [self a b]
>> second o
== [make object! [
        a: 1
        b: 2
    ] 1 2]
```

in any way...

```
>> pick o 1
== [self a b]
>> pick o 2
== [make object! [
        a: 1
        b: 2
    ] 1 2]
```

but there's a third "table" (a block) which seems to be undocumented and this one is only accessible using third function

```
>> third o
== [a: 1 b: 2]

>> pick o 3
** Script Error: Out of range or past end
** Near: pick o 3
```

what is supposed to be this third block?

something similar seem to occur in functions but this time both third and pick perform well:

```
>> f: func [a] [print a]
>> first :f
== [a]
>> second :f
== [print a]
>> third :f
== [a]
>> pick :f 1
== [a]
>> pick :f 2
== [print a]
>> pick :f 3
== [a]
```

first block is params, second block is body but what does this third block represents in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed:

```
>> third o
== [a: 1 b: 2]

>> pick o 3
** Script Error: Out of range or past end
** Near: pick o 3
```

...which is odd.  It seems in Rebol2 that THIRD was not purely synonymous with PICK of 3, for some edge cases.  :-/

In Rebol3 this is no longer the case.  But what's also not any longer the case is that in Rebol3 positional picking isn't available for objects or functions:

```
>> pick object [a: 1 b: 2] 1
** Script error: pick does not allow object! for its aggregate argument
```

Instead you have WORDS-OF, VALUES-OF, and BODY-OF:

```
>> words-of object [a: 1 b: 2]
== [a b]

>> values-of object [a: 1 b: 2]
== [1 2]

>> body-of object [a: 1 b: 2]
== [
    a: 1
    b: 2
]
```

These have been backported to Rebol2 in an built-in library called "R2/Forward", so you can (and should) use these functions in place of positional pick.

You noticed getting similar answers from FIRST and THIRD with:

```
>> f: func [a] [print a]

>> first :f
== [a]

>> second :f
== [print a]

>> third :f
== [a]

>> pick :f 1
== [a]

>> pick :f 2
== [print a]

>> pick :f 3
== [a]
```

> first block is params, second block is body but what does this third block represents in a function?

Your example was too simple to notice that the distinction of the third was that it was the SPEC-OF, because your spec only contained words.  So SPEC-OF was equal to WORDS-OF.  Adding a type constraint to your spec reveals the difference.

```
>> f: func [a [integer!]] [print a]

>> first :f
== [a]

>> third :f
== [a [integer!]]
```

Once again, Rebol2 via R2/Forward offers you WORDS-OF, SPEC-OF, and BODY-OF for functions.  And once again, avoid using positional picks for these properties.

Answer (score 3):

`Third` returns object definition.

```
>> body: [a: 1 b: 2]
== [a: 1 b: 2]
>> obj: context body
>> equal? body third obj
== true
>> strict-equal? body third obj
== true
```

It's same as `body-of` in Rebol 2.7.7 and higher and Rebol 3.